# Angular (load) on a background-image

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 5 and I'm trying to get a loading icon while a background image of a div is loading.
I have no problem with this if its a normal img but if I try to have it as a background it doesnt work.

here is some example code

*app.component.html*

```
<div class="test" [someDirective]="'some/otherImg.jpg'"></div>  
<img class="test" [someDirective]="'some/OtherImg.jpg'">
```

*app.component.css*

```
.test{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

*some.directive.ts*

```
import { Directive, ViewChild, Input, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[someDirective]'
})
export class SomeDirective {
  @Input() someDirective:string;

  constructor(private element:ElementRef){
    element.nativeElement.src = 'some/imgUrl.gif';
    element.nativeElement.style = "background-image: url('some/imgUrl.gif')";
  } 

  @HostListener('load', ['$event'])
  onLoad() {
    this.element.nativeElement.src = "some/otherImg.jpg";
    this.element.nativeElement.style = "background-image: url('some/otherImg.jpg')";
  }
}
```

is there a way I can get this to work so that the background is also loaded in the same way a normal image would be?

I should mention that I have no issue with getting the loading gif to act as the background-image that works fine but it doesnt change.

Comment: try to write a absoulte url...I mean ../some/img.jpg

Comment: My bad I should have been more specific with the problem. The url isnt the problem. They are just exaples not the real urls. I should have paid a bit more attention when making the example... sorry

Comment: The loading icon and image work fine for the <img> its just the <div> where its a background-image that causes problems since it seems like the (load) only checks if content is loaded and not the style

Comment: you dont close the image tag <img/> the / is missing

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is not working as you are expecting is because CSS loads are not triggering DOM load events. After some research it seems like the way people are solving this (even outside of Angular) is to load the image in a hidden img element and use that to trigger the event. Its pretty messy but that seems to be the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Do not manipulate the `ElementRef` directly. Use the `Renderer` class. Try this implementation with observables. Just like the zmanc  mentioned, you cannot use the background-url technique. Stick with the `src` attribute.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[load]',
})
export class LoadImageDirective {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'load')
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(() => this.setImage())

    this.setPlaceholder();

  }

  private setPlaceholder() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(
      this.el.nativeElement,
      'src', `https://via.placeholder.com/50x50`
    )
  }


  private setImage = () => {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(
      this.el.nativeElement,
      'src', `https://http.cat/400`
    )
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q3rbxz)